# Inserting specific file at index of a stream

Tags: gulp

Basicly this gulp script finds the 'file1,file2,file3' in a folder, builds its dependencies (which are in the same folder) and add it all to 1 file.

Now, my problem is, i have a custom file which i have to put in after file2. How can i achieve this?

```
function gatherAMD(stream, file) {
  var moduleId = file.path.match(/file\.(.+)\.js/)[1];
  return stream.pipe(amdOptimize(`file.${moduleId}`, {
      baseUrl: "fileslocation/location",
      exclude: [ 'jquery' ]
  }));
}



gulp.task("js", function() {
  var included = [];
  var files = "file1,file2,file3"
  var stream = null;

  if (files.indexOf(",") == -1) {
    stream = gulp.src('fileslocation/location/file.'+ files+ '.js', { base: "fileslocation/location"});
  } else {
    stream =  gulp.src(`fileslocation/location/file.{${files}}.js`, { base: "fileslocation/location"});
  }

  return stream.pipe(debug())
          .pipe(foreach(gatherAMD))
          .pipe(filter(function(file) {
              if (included.indexOf(file.path) === -1) {
                  included.push(file.path);
                  return true;
              }  else {
                  return false;
              }
          }))
          .pipe(concat({path: 'fileslocation/custom.js', base: 'fileslocation'}))
          .pipe(gulp.dest("fileslocation"));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use [map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-stream) for checking the current file in the stream, and then adding it from some logic and then using [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) to add a file to the stream.

Something like,

```
return stream.pipe(debug())
          .pipe(foreach(gatherAMD))
          .pipe(filter(function(file) {
              if (included.indexOf(file.path) === -1) {
                  included.push(file.path);
                  return true;
              }  else {
                  return false;
              }
          }))
          .pipe(map(function(file, callback) {
              if (file.relative === 'file2.js') {
                   // inject file to the stream here
              }
              callback(null, file);
          }))
          .pipe(concat({path: 'fileslocation/custom.js', base: 'fileslocation'}))
          .pipe(gulp.dest("fileslocation"));
```